# Javascript clipboard manipulation after section has been copied from website

Tags: javascript, html, web, clipboard, copy-paste

When I copy a section of test from [this website](http://www.metro.co.uk/weird/876559-snow-white-the-albino-squirrel-saved-after-attack-by-grey-cousins)

my clipboard gets extra text appended to the end of it saying "Read more: " then the url of the page I was reading (plus a unique looking string on the end)

How have they done this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made some reverse engineering and it looks like this script is responsible for clipboard manipulation:

http://tcr.tynt.com/ti.js (use http://jsbeautifier.org/ to see uncompressed code)

See the introduction movie on this website:

http://www.tynt.com/

Technically I don't know how is it done, looks like they don't use Flash but make use of **getSelection()** function and **copy, contextmenu** events.

Comment: It is a little bit illegal to use their code. And I think they've renamed the functions to make it harder to read.

Comment: They've compressed the code to make it smaller but also hard to read. As for using their code, I don't know what are you referring to, but getSelection() is a build-in function. And you CAN use their code legally on their terms by registering on their site (tynt.com). We are wondering here how their code works, and there is nothing illegal in reverse engineering.

Answer (score 2):

When your select text on their page (before the Copy happens) a zero-height div containing the extra text (*"Read more: ....."*) is created off the page (`position: absolute; top: -1000px`) and that text is then added to the selection.

So when you copy your selected text, you are also copying the text that is hidden off the page.