# Providing alternative text for copy/paste

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, clipboard

I'm fairly certain I've done this before, but I can't find any documentation about it.  I'm finding this issue is oddly hard to research.

I'd like to display one version (A) of a bit of text on screen.  However, when the text is copied, a different version of that text (B) is actually copied to the clipboard.  In practice, A and B might be very similar, but the technique should allow for A and B to be completely different strings.

For example, if I use a `<div>` to display the following to the user:

`<div>This is a really long...</div>`

...and the user selects the div and issues a "copy" on it, I would like the text that is placed on the clipboard to be:

`This is a really long bit of text that is too large to display on-screen, but should be fully intact when copy/pasted.`

(Of course, my app would separately take care of shortening the first instance of the string and adding the ellipses.)

I seem to recall this being possible with simple HTML/CSS, but the details are eluding me... Thoughts?

Comment: Couple of similar questions, might give something to work with: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17527870/how-does-trello-access-the-users-clipboard, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8820445/javascript-clipboard-manipulation-after-section-has-been-copied-from-website

Comment: On a personal side note – I’d be pissed at any site that did this. When I mark and copy something, then most of the times because I want to put it into a search engine, or paste it verbatim into some document I’m working with – getting something totally different there would be of no use to me, and I would feel “cheated” by a site that does this. (In a limited environment there might be legitimate uses cases for something like this though.)

Comment: Thanks for your insight.  I'm planning on using it on a backend that displays large amounts of data in a table.  Some cells contain a *lot* of text that makes the rows incredibly tall (since there are so many wrapped lines in the cell).  The idea is to display a preview of the text, but when the user copies the text, he/she gets the full version.  Speaking of which, writing this comment reminds me - I think I might have solved this by using HTML/CSS to effectively "disable" the soft wrapping of the cell...

Comment: **Of course, the best solution is to probably just provide a "copy to clipboard" button that copies the full, untrimmed data.**  Regardless, I thought I'd ask, because I remembered having done something like this in the past.

Comment: While I'm still interested in a possible answer to this question, the approach I ended up using (for the case described in the comments above) was: `table td { white-space: nowrap; max-width: 300px; overflow: hidden; }`

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve this problem using just CSS.

```css
.css{
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="css" style="max-width: 17.5ch;">This is a really long bit of text that is too large to display on-screen, but should be fully intact when copy/pasted.</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The class 'css' uses:
-text-overflow, to place the ellipsis after the text,
-overflow, to prevent the text from fully showing,
-white-space, to prevent text from having multiple lines,
-and the div has max-width, to define where to replace text with ellipsis.

This makes it so that all elements with class 'css' will have their text replaced with ellipsis once it exceeds the max-width limit.